# Reference for equations in boiboites.sty

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am using the very nice package [boiboites.sty](http://snouffy.free.fr/blog-fr/index.php/post/2009/09/30/Des-jolies-boites-en-LaTeX-pour-encadrer-les-th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes) in my work, in conjunction with the external compilation of the tikz and pgf figures. I am having some problems to use references defined in the boiboites environment outside of it, as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{boiboites}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize 

\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=blue, background=cyan, titlebackground=cyan,titleboxcolor = black]{impbox}{}{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{impbox}[Some equation]
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:1}
        a = b
    \end{equation}
\end{impbox}

I want to talk about equation \ref{eq:1} here.

\end{document}
```

which produces the following result :

[image: boiboites with external compilation of figures]

My document is very large, and uses a lot of "boiboites". I saw a possibility (can't find the link again) of fixing this problem by applying additional compilation steps for each "boiboites", but this is not viable here. Does anyone know an alternative ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It works here using updated TeXlive 2014 on Linux. Did you compile it twice in a row?

Comment: Yes I sure did. Everything is up-to-date, I am using TexLive/TexShop on Mac. The "compile" line is :pdflatex --shell-escape --file-line-error --synctex=1

Comment: Your labels are lost. Forget `boiboites`. Start using `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `boîte` (box) is built using tikz and so it is externalized (thus the labels are lost). One solution may be to add `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable`. But If you want to externalize the content of the box the solution will not work.

**Newcommand** (you can also define a new environment) :

```
\newboxedtheorem[boxcolor=blue, background=cyan, titlebackground=cyan,titleboxcolor = black]{impbox}{}{} 
\newcommand{\thperso}[2]{%
\tikzexternaldisable
\begin{impbox}[#1]
#2
\end{impbox}
\tikzexternalenable%
}
```

**New box syntax:**

```
\thperso{Some equation}{%
    \begin{equation} 
        a = b\label{eq:1}
    \end{equation}%
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot ! I also upped @HarishKumar answer, since I guess he is right in the end. But this is the last year of PhD and there is no time for going again through all the manuscript ;)

However I have no need for the impbox to be externalized, since they always only contain equations, so that is perfectly ok for my case.